# Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults

Tags: grafana

I have this problem on an ec2 instance. According to the documentation, the config file is at "/etc/grafana/grafana.ini" and I checked and it's there but I still can't get it to start. I tried "grafana-server --config /etc/grafana/grafana.ini" but I'm getting " “Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults, make sure homepath command line parameter is set or working directory
is homepath”

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue but working docker in an image without systemctl. I created an startup script and it worked

```
exec grafana-server                                         \
  --homepath="$GF_PATHS_HOME"                               \
  --config="$GF_PATHS_CONFIG"                               \
  --packaging=docker                                        \
  "$@"                                                      \
  cfg:default.log.mode="console"                            \
  cfg:default.paths.data="$GF_PATHS_DATA"                   \
  cfg:default.paths.logs="$GF_PATHS_LOGS"                   \
  cfg:default.paths.plugins="$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS"             \
  cfg:default.paths.provisioning="$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING"
```